# Отображение HTML с картинками, используя Html.IImageGetter в Xamarin Forms Renderer

Tags: c#, xamarin

Как работать с `Html.IImageGetter`?

У меня есть строка `html` и нужно ее отобразить (как в браузере) так, чтобы в ней показывались мои картинки в теге `<img>`.

Попробовал пример `HtmlFormattedLabel`, но там отображает только текст, а картинку выдает в виде голубого квадрата.

Вот код:

```
public class HtmlFormattedLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var view = (HtmlFormattedLabel)Element;

        if (view == null)
            return;

        var image = new NewsImageGetter();
        image.GetDrawable(view.Text);
        Control.SetText(Html.FromHtml(view.Text, image, null), TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
    }
}

public class NewsImageGetter : Java.Lang.Object, Html.IImageGetter
{
    public Drawable GetDrawable(string source)
    {
        Drawable drawable;
        Bitmap bitMap;
        BitmapFactory.Options bitMapOption;
        try
        {
            bitMapOption = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bitMapOption.InJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bitMapOption.InPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.Argb4444;
            bitMapOption.InPurgeable = true;
            bitMapOption.InInputShareable = true;
            var url = new Java.Net.URL(source);

            bitMap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(url.OpenStream(), null, bitMapOption);
            drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitMap);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }

        drawable.SetBounds(0, 0, bitMapOption.OutWidth, bitMapOption.OutHeight);
        return drawable;
    }
}
```

Вот html строка:
`string text = "<p style=\"text-align:center;\">" + "<img src=\"devyatka.ru/images/bx/2015/10/…\" " + "alt=\"\" width=\"285\" height=\"191\" /></p>\r\n" + "<p style=\"text-align:center;\"><em><span style=\"font-size:large;\">" + "Размещена иструкция по получению диплома и приложения к нему." + "</span></em></p>";`

И результат работы приложения:

[image: Результат работы]

Comment: Добавьте пример строки `html` и как ее пытались отобразить. Еще хорошо бы увидеть скриншот результата

Comment: Примеры нужно в вопрос включать, нажмите на кнопку `править` и добавьте

Comment: Спасибо за замечание gil9red уже испраивл

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем за помощь. Вот решение на данный вопрос:

```
    public class HtmlFormattedLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var view = (HtmlFormattedLabel)Element;

        Control.SetLineSpacing(11, 1);

        Control.MovementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.Instance;
        Control.TextFormatted = Html.FromHtml(view.Text, new NewsImageGetter(), null);
    }

    public class NewsImageGetter : Java.Lang.Object, Html.IImageGetter
    {
        Drawable drawable;

        public Drawable GetDrawable(string source)
        {
            var result = SetupData(source);

            return result;
        }

        Drawable SetupData(string source)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                URL url = new URL(source);
                var conn = url.OpenConnection();
                conn.Connect();
                var Test = conn.InputStream;
                drawable = Drawable.CreateFromStream(Test, "");
                drawable.SetBounds(0, 0, drawable.IntrinsicWidth, drawable.IntrinsicHeight);
                Test.Close();
            }).Wait();
            return drawable;
        }
    }
}
```